# Exact range of brightness for tm1637 component using Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

I have recently started working on basic programs in Raspberry Pi using Python. With reference to the repository found at https://github.com/timwaizenegger/raspberrypi-examples/blob/master/actor-led-7segment-4numbers/tm1637.py, I am slightly confused as to what the maximum value of brightness is when displaying any values on the display. Some tutorials suggest that the min-max range is between 0 and 1. There are other resources that suggest 0 to be the minimum value and 7 to be the max value.

My confusion here is that when I set the brightness as 7.9, the values are still being displayed; however, when I set the value as 8.0, the whole screen goes dark/blank.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.